# How to install Visual Web Developer Express

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-web-developer

Im trying to install Visual Web Developer Express. I click the [install-button](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) and run the Web Platform Installer which then tell me I have to restart my computer (SQLServer Express R2 requires reboot...). I restart, the installer continues and tells me yet again I have to restart (for the same reason). I restart, and its all over again...

So I googled the problem and found others with the same issue, but none of the presented solutions worked for me. I didnt have this PendingFileRename-key-thingy in the registre.... and I even tried uninstalling all occurances of "SQL Server *" and reinstalled the offline-installation of SQL Server R2 and then tried to Visual Web Dev install again. With the exact same result.

Now Im clueless and very frustraded... How can it be so much problem with this Web Installer? I read about the same problem that where several years old. And its still not solved? Gosh... Ive spent a good deal of a day trying to install this now. Only to be able to install the WP7-SDK in my next step.

Anyon else having this problem?

Is there any offline/redist install of Visual Web Developer Express? (cant find any)

Answer (score 2):

did you try this link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709959

you should be able to install VS web dev without SQl server

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and installing VS Web Dev individually via the above link worked for me.